# Word for kids who have become resistant to scoldings and punishments?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The parents / Teachers punish these types of kids frequently . As a result they just no longer fear and remain unaffected no matter how much they are scolded. For instance, my mom rebukes my younger brother so often that he has started taking it lightly . I've even seen him tittering while receiving reprimands from mom.

Comment: [_Brave_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brave), [_dauntless_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dauntless), [_unflinching_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unflinching) ?

Comment: Also, you should provide an example sentence as requested in the _single-word-request_ tag description

Comment: You could also consider ***churlish***

Comment: .... traumatized

Comment: Unruly, spoiled, froward, and jaded all say related things. (as do the answers already given) What emphasis do you seek? Are you looking to emphasize the lack of control, the lack of respect, the attitude as a jerk, or something else?

Comment: Accepting neologisms? How about "scoffma"?

Comment: Please do not create the example sentence if you are not the person who needs the word.

Comment: @TheNate The question was reasonably clear that the emphasis is on the lack of effect being due to familiarity. ie 'as a result', 'so often that'.

Comment: I don't read the question as clear on connotation.

Comment: Normal teenager?

Answer (score 15):

[Inure](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/inure)

> inure VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1. (usually be inured to) Accustom (someone) to something, especially something unpleasant: ‘*these children have been inured to violence*’

Per your example

> This boy is so **inured to** scolding that no amount of it will
>   deter him from his mischief.

Answer (score 10):

It's not *quite* what you're after. However, an ***incorrigible*** person is somebody who cannot be deterred or reformed in any way, including through punishment or admonishment.

- This boy is so incorrigible that no amount of scolding will deter him from his mischief.

Here's a definition from Google:

> incorrigible
>
> ɪnˈkɒrɪdʒɪb(ə)l/
>
> adjective: incorrigible
>
> 1. (of a person or their behaviour) not able to be changed or reformed.
>
> > "she's an incorrigible flirt"
>
> **synonyms**: inveterate, habitual, confirmed, hardened.

Answer (score 5):

Those kids got ***hardened*** by the scoldings/punishments that they got and no longer fear them.

> This boy is so ***hardened*** that no amount of scolding will deter
>   him from his mischief.

ODO:

> **[hardened](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hardened)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** [attributive] Very experienced in a particular job or activity and therefore not easily upset by its more unpleasant aspects:
>   ‘hardened police officers’
>
> ‘Experienced sportsmen become hardened and learn to deal with this
>   sort of thing.’

Answer (score 3):

Consider **wayward**.

Definition:

> - tending to behave in ways that are not socially acceptable
> - not going or moving in the intended direction
> - self-willed and rebellious

Example:

> Above all have faith in yourself and your child and you can see the
>   result in the years to come as your *wayward* teen grows into the adult
>   you can be proud of. It will be your crowning achievement.

Answer (score 3):

Desensitized, literally, 'to become less sensitive to', is another possibility. Ex:"He became desensitized to the pain of the punishments."

Answer (score 2):

**habituated**

[From a Google search of the word](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=habituated) we get the definition and synonyms:

- definition:  make or become accustomed or used to something.
- synonyms:   accustomed, familiarized, adapted, adjusted, attuned, acclimatized, acculturated, conditioned

Used in the sample sentence:

*This boy is so habituated that no amount of scolding will deter him from his mischief.*

Reasoning for habituated working in this instance:

This speaks to the OP prompt about the parents/teachers frequent punishment being a primary driver of the immunity to any amount of scolding.

Comment: I like it, but it would be better if you give your source.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [numb](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/numb) [TFD]

> 2. Emotionally unresponsive; indifferent: numb to yet another appeal.

Answer (score 0):

**Wild**

Example use in your sentence:

> This boy is so ***wild*** that no amount of scolding will deter him from his mischief.

This fits because one common phrase is to **run wild**, defined as:

> To show lack of restraint or control:
>
> *Those children are allowed to run wild.*

Source: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wild)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go with **stubborn**:

[From Google:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+stubborn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

stub·born
adjective

> having or showing dogged determination not to change one's attitude or position on something, especially in spite of good arguments or reasons to do so.

Example:

> This boy is so stubborn that no amount of scolding will deter him from his mischief.

Comment: Nice, but please, include the name of the dictionary where you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Rebellious

[Dfn. Merriam-Webster:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebellious)

> adjective  re·bel·lious -yəs
>
> Simple Definition of rebellious
>
> : fighting against a government
>
> : refusing to obey rules or authority or to accept normal standards of behavior, dress, etc.
>
> : having or showing a tendency to rebel

Answer (score 0):

*intractable* is related but probably not an exact fit

> This boy is so intractable that no amount of scolding will deter him from his mischief

Definitions include:

> Difficult to persuade or keep under control, as in behavior

([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=intractable))

> not easily governed, managed, or directed

Example:

> an intractable child who deliberately does the opposite of whatever he is told

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intractable))

> difficult to influence or direct

([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intractable))